# Trello API: determine when a card changed name?

Tags: api, trello

I use card names to keep track of useful information (I'm sure this can be done in other ways, but for my use case, it is a great fit).

I am wondering if I can find the history of card name changes using the trello API? For example:

```
Card1 was created with name X by userX on DateX
Card1 name updated to Y by userY on DateY
Card1 name updated to Z by userZ on DateZ
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to be able to see a history of changes to the name of a card.

I'm still learning the Trello API, but my guess is to check out the "Actions" API. Trello does an amazing job of tracking everything that happens inside of it. So, you should be able to find the data that you want with that.
https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/action#get-1-actions-idaction-card

You can try playing with the API Sandbox and use this call to see the list of actions from all of your boards
"Trello.get('/members/me/boards/?actions=all', success, error);"
Sandbox URL: https://developers.trello.com/sandbox

Additionally, if you're looking for ways to automatically watch future name changes, check out the "Webhooks" API, which allows you to receive updates from the Trello servers when certain objects are updated. It's also available in the API docs, but I can only share up to two links right now. :-)